# Gain of the system

Tags: homework

There is a transfer function $G(s)= \frac{-2(s+4)}{(s+3)(s+2)(s+1)} $. Find its gain $K$. I'm not sure, what does this question mean. Is there any konstant gain for this system? I tried to find its frequency characteristic.

$$G(s)= \frac{-2(s+4)}{(s+3)(s+2)(s+1)}  = \frac{-2(j\omega+4)}{(j\omega+3)(j\omega+2)(j\omega+1)} = \frac{-8(1+\frac{j\omega}{4})}{(1+\frac{j\omega}{3})(1+\frac{j\omega}{2})(1+j\omega)\cdot 6}=\frac{-\frac{4}{3}(1+\frac{j\omega}{4})}{(1+\frac{j\omega}{3})(1+\frac{j\omega}{2})(1+j\omega)} $$

$20\cdot \log_{10}|-\frac{4}{3}| = 2.5\space dB$

I think the frequency characteristic of this system looks like this:
[image]

Am I right? If so, those are gains for every frequency.

If there was written to find DC gain, I would use the formula:
$$DCgain=\lim_{s\to 0} s\frac1s G(s) = \frac{-2(0+4)}{(0+3)(0+2)(0+1)} = -\frac86 = -\frac43$$

Is that the gain K I am looking for?

As I said. I don't understand the question. Gain of the system like this... what does it use to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the gain of that system is frequency variant. One other way to calculate the [gain](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbsoluteSquare.html) is multiplying the transfer function by the conjugate of itself. As for K, it's easy to find that value by inspection.